merging two queries to one query results in some records being dropped
I have two queries that are laid out as follows:
Query name - week1
SELECT 
    BERTHAGE.BOAT, BERTHAGE.LOCATION, BERTHAGE.BERTH_WEEK, BERTHAGE.BERTH_YEAR
FROM 
    BERTHAGE
WHERE 
    (((BERTHAGE.BERTH_WEEK) = 1) 
     AND ((BERTHAGE.BERTH_YEAR) = 2024));

The result of this query is 82 records
Query name - week2
SELECT 
    BERTHAGE.BOAT, BERTHAGE.LOCATION, BERTHAGE.BERTH_WEEK, BERTHAGE.BERTH_YEAR 
FROM 
    BERTHAGE 
WHERE 
    (((BERTHAGE.BERTH_WEEK) = 2) 
     AND ((BERTHAGE.BERTH_YEAR) = 2024));

The result of this query is 80 records.
The goal is to then use both queries together and put this into a report. Which currently I have set up as follows:
Query name – W1W2_Result
SELECT 
    BOAT.BOAT_NAME, week1.BERTH_WEEK, week2.BERTH_WEEK 
FROM 
    (BOAT
LEFT JOIN 
    week1 ON BOAT.BOAT_ID = week1.BOAT) 
LEFT JOIN 
    week2 ON BOAT.BOAT_ID = week2.BOAT 
WHERE 
    (((week1.BERTH_YEAR) = 2024) 
     AND ((week2.BERTH_YEAR) = 2024)) 
ORDER BY 
    BOAT.BOAT_NAME;

The result of this query is 78 records.
The problem I am encountering is that when a boat is in week 1, but not in week 2 (or vice versa) that boat will get dropped from the merged query W1W2_Result.
I’ve gone through week1 and week2  and compared the results and the records that are missing from W1W2_Result are exclusive to either week1 or week2. Any BOAT that appears in both queries, will appear in W1W2_Result.

it seems that "select * from week1 union select * from week2" should work

Or maybe one query with OR operator: WHERE (BERTH_WEEK = 1 OR BERTH_WEEK = 2) AND BERTH_YEAR = 2024.

Or maybe: BERTH_WEEK IN(1,2) AND BERTH_YEAR = 2024. Or maybe: BERTH_WEEK <=2 AND BERTH_YEAR = 2024.
